# Using TS conditional types to narrow to numeric properties

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with conditional types and trying to get this this to validate. Interestingly, the test() function *does* validate if I pass "val" as the parameter, and fails if I pass "name" ...which is the expected behavior. However, Typescript apparently doesn't think o[p] can be relied on to be a number, and throws this:

**Operator '+=' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never; }[keyof T]]'.**

Am I misunderstanding the usage somehow? I thought 'never' would prohibit any parameters that were not explicitly a number...

```
class Test {
    public static SumParam<T>
        (t: T[], p:{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never }[keyof T]): number {
        let n:number = 0;
        for (let o of t) {
            n += o[p]; //Operator '+=' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never; }[keyof T]]'.
        }
        return (n);
    }
    public test(): void {
        Test.SumParam(
            [{ name: "alice", val: 3 },
            { name: "bob", val: 4 }],
            "val"); //validates
        Test.SumParam(
            [{ name: "alice", val: 3 },
            { name: "bob", val: 4 }],
            "name"); //Argument of type '"name"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"val"'.
    }
}
```

The fact that the compiler narrows and recognizes that 'val' is the only enumerable property extending number ...doesn't that imply that the conditional syntax is working...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript will not be able to follow conditional types that still have unresolved type parameters in them. As such it will not be able to know that `o[p]` is of type number.

If you don't mind having the error on the items in the array, you can type the function in a way that allows typescript to know `o[p]` is number:

```
class Test {
    public static SumParam<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof T>
        (t: T[], p: K): number {
        let n:number = 0;
        if (!t) return (n);
        for (let o of t) {
            n += o[p]; //ok.
        }
        return (n);
    }
    public test(): void {
        Test.SumParam(
            [{ name: "alice", val: 3 },
            { name: "bob", val: 4 }],
            "val"); //ok, no error here
        Test.SumParam(
            [{ name: "alice", val: 3 }, // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
            { name: "bob", val: 4 }], // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
            "name"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I don't want to limit the types in the incoming object (or have that error). What is unresolved in the original example... simply the T? It seems that if there is no keyof T which satisfies 'number', it would resolve 'never', so it should not matter what T is...

Comment: Interestingly I find that just changing the incoming type to <T extends any> allows it to validate. If T is unresolved, shouldn't it be assumed that it extends any??

Comment: @joshstrike the version above does limit the incoming object, you still get errors on the second call. Unresolved means that it still contains free type parameters (such as `T`)

Comment: @joshstrike `T extends any` will effectively disable type checking, `o[p]` will be of type any and no errors will appear no matter what you do with `o[p]`

Comment: @joshstrike a type assertion is also an option `o[p] as unknown as number`

Comment: @joshstrike I misread you comment about not wanting the error.. shouldn't the second call produce an error since you expect only `number` keys to be passed in ?

Comment: TS won't allow o[p] to be coerced into unknown or number... however with <T extends any> the type checking on the key DOES work (it allows "val" and disallows "name"). Yes the second call should produce an error. But there should be no error on the first call (which is where with Record<K, number> we would have an error on name:"Alice")... I think <T extends any> makes the most sense but why shouldn't <T> already be considered to extend any until it is narrowed and resolved?

Comment: @joshstrike have you tried the code above ? It does not produce an error on the first call. excess property checks do not kick in here, since the type must be `T` it can have more properties

Comment: @joshstrike also `any` is a dangerous type, since it is at the same time a super type for all types and a sub type of all types and is assignable to and from any other type, considering `T` by default as `any` would allow any code to be written against `T` in the method (ie `o.nopeNotHere` would be valid). If no constraint is specified `T` is more akin to `unknown` you can't do anything with it unless you use assertions

Comment: Okay, I see - the first call doesn't have the error. It seems like a very strange way to narrow T instead of K but this makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I bit other error for `name`, but in general it works fine:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUNaAHArgEYgCWw0yYSZ0AyvgLYAKYATmAwDwDS08AHkngA7ACYxkrEsIDmAGjh9BI8WmgBtANbwAntGnRuAXQBc0YY0LxW0AL4A+ABRIzsdUYW4z3AJRmLDFY2GNg4YTgg8CjCJgFB0AC80AAMANxY4eEAZgD2No6RKDnQOVnQSD5oGZk1wtAA1Ek56rhG6aE1ttU1rFH4rHWOwj7t4V0deESk5ELIjn7QAG45JKJVE+EIyAB09MxsHI7dNWHqqOYc8GYARGDT8NcKi3dmAMx2cscnasKXN4Q5QiPJYvaAAFjsHi+J2uzxA1xG0AA9Ei4asqIhoTgtkhdowWOwGEcNiczhcGFdoLd7sC4W8PljMudfhT-oDaaCIbYoSSatcWQ9ESi4DpcPBoABySTSGQS-QwYQ5FCQCAkGS-YjipDFJCi8USuLWCXbY7jWxAA)

```
class Test {
  public static SumParam<K extends string, T extends { [key in K]: number }>(t: T[], p: K): number {
        let n:number = 0;
        for (let o of t) {
            n += o[p];
        }
        return (n);
    }
    public test(): void {
        Test.SumParam(
            [{ name: "alice", val: 3 },
            { name: "bob", val: 4 }],
            "val"); //validates
        Test.SumParam(
            [{ name: "alice", val: 3 },
            { name: "bob", val: 4 }],
            "name"); // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    }
}
```